# How to identify location of the users behind each Facebook page like

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ip-address

Abstract question here.

When data journalists like at the New York Times do stories where they identify the say county-level location of each user behind the likes on a Facebook page, how is this done? I presume they're somehow getting the IP address behind each like. Can that be done with SDK, or are they likely doing something different entirely? (I do understand from other threads that the api cannot be used to identify individual users.)

Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: In page insights I believe you can see some aggregated data.

Comment: To clarify, I mean like the public page of a politician, business or product for which I'm not an administration. For instance, for this article (https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/02/24/movies/oscars-state-by-state-movie-popularity.html) they seem to have pulled the county-level location of each user who has liked the page of a film.

Comment: _"I presume they're somehow getting the IP address behind each like."_ - Facebook doesn’t give such 3rd parties access to such private information. _"Can that be done with SDK, or are they likely doing something different entirely?"_ - with the SDK only with admin access; they are using something else.